# Visual Basic.NET: Saving an application?

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, save, loading

I am a beginning programmer in VB.NET and I was wondering how to save my application when button1 is clicked, and then load my application when button2 is clicked. My application has several different forms and classes etc. Is there a simple way to save all of the different forms and the changes to those forms that the user may have made, and then load them again? If this is too complicated of a process for a beginner, then I can just forget it for now, but if anyone knows a relatively simple way to do this, I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what are you wanting to save, is your user actually making changes to your user interface or are you talking about some sort of database

Comment: Say, entering new data in text boxes, changing universal variables, etc. That's what the user would be changing.

Comment: then Douglas's answer should work for you

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different options.  The easiest thing is probably going to be for you to take a look at the [`My.Settings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx) class.